# How to read GCDetails

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a java program that stores a lot of data, on a whim I tried running it with the following VM argument:  -XX:+PrintGCDetails

On program closure, it printed:

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 238016K, used 100138K [0x00000000eaeb0000, 0x00000000fd460000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 224640K, 38% used [0x00000000eaeb0000,0x00000000f0378dc0,0x00000000f8a10000)
  from space 13376K, 99% used [0x00000000fbd50000,0x00000000fca51a60,0x00000000fca60000)
  to   space 10240K, 0% used [0x00000000fca60000,0x00000000fca60000,0x00000000fd460000)
 PSOldGen        total 92608K, used 88569K [0x00000000c0c00000, 0x00000000c6670000, 0x00000000eaeb0000)
  object space 92608K, 95% used [0x00000000c0c00000,0x00000000c627e660,0x00000000c6670000)
 PSPermGen       total 64256K, used 64244K [0x00000000bba00000, 0x00000000bf8c0000, 0x00000000c0c00000)
  object space 64256K, 99% used [0x00000000bba00000,0x00000000bf8bd300,0x00000000bf8c0000)
```

I'm assuming the 99% (and 95%) used portions suggest I need to do some tweaking.  I'm just not sure of what.

Comment: what additional options have u passed to JVM. this information can go a long way in us helping you.

Comment: Is your application long running? Unless you are hit with some issues like longer GC pauses or OOM exceptions, you don't have to worry. Are you facing any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Well the first 99% are just fine:

> from space 13376K, 99% used

this is just how the GC in the young generation works. Objects go from Eden to Survivor spaces(*from space* and *to space*) on minor GC and from survivor to old generation on major GC.

While the second one:

> object space 92608K, 95% used

is something that you should worry about, sort of. Old generation has about 100MB of space according to your logs, which is too little usually, but depends on the code you execute.

You should measure your program more to get the accurate results, but still it seems that you are creating some long lived objects, which pile up in the old generation.